# Performance concern with a React.js looping picture slideshow

Tags: css, animation, reactjs, slideshow, gif

We want to display a looping slideshow of pictures that looks like a gif. The current result is visible at this url: https://figuredevices.com.

Our current approach is using opacity to show or hide slides:

```
class SlideShow extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentSlide: 0
    };
    this.interval = null;

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.transitionToNextSlide.bind(this), 200);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    if(this.interval){
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  }

  transitionToNextSlide() {

    let nextSlide = this.state.currentSlide + 1;

    if (nextSlide == this.props.slides.length) {
        nextSlide = 0;
    }
    this.setState({currentSlide: nextSlide});
  }


  render () {

    let slides = this.props.pictures.map((picture, idx) => {
      let slideContainerStyle = {
        opacity: this.state.currentSlide == idx ? 1 : 0
      };
      return(
        <div style={slideContainerStyle} key={idx}>
          <Slide picture={picture}/>
        </div>
      );
    })

    let containerStyle = {
      width:'100%'
    };

    return (
      <div style={containerStyle}>
          {slides}
      </div>
    );

  }

};
```

Pictures are loaded 5 by five into `this.props.picture`. The number of pictures is not bounded and I am worried about performance as this number grows. There are two things that don't feel right to me:

- The map operation in the render method is traversing a whole array every 200ms only to change two css properties.
- The DOM is growing a lot in size but most of nodes are hidden

Would you suggest a better approach, maybe using [animation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) or [react-motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion) ?

Comment: Why not just have a single `<Slide>` and update the `picture` prop every 200ms?

Comment: If you want to keep the opacity transition.. you just need two slides. with a `next` props to target the animation `<Slide next={isNext} />` and as @Aaron said just change the props accordingly.

Comment: I didn't see any opacity fade, but yeah: if you want a transition you could use `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` and just replace the `<Slide>` with the current picture.

Comment: Indeed I think ReactCSSTransitionGroup is more for transition effects that I do not want. I have tried setting with a single slide but the transition between slides was not smooth because I was loosing the opacity transition, which make @azium proposition very clever :-). Let me give it a try.

Comment: `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` basically does what azium describes for you: when the element is swapped (by looking at the `key`) it will create a second element to fade in, while it fades out the previous element, then when the transition is done it will remove the old element so you are left with just the new element. It should be very performant.

Comment: @azium I have tried the two slides solution. However a new problem arises: pictures are re-fetched from the server at every loop, which I really do not want. Do you have any idea to prevent pictures from being re-fetched. I am thinking about base64 encded images maybe ?

Comment: So don't do that? Fetch them ahead of time, or fetch 4, 8, 10 at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain all of your pictures as an array, and every 200ms, increment the array index. Then, instead of displaying all of the pictures every single time, just have it display the picture at your current index. This is a lot better because you're only returning one photo ever instead of a bunch of invisible ones :)

Note: I wasn't able to test this, so I'm not sure if everything is exactly syntactically correct, but this is the general idea. Every 200ms, increment the slideIndex. Then, always return a div with only the one picture you want to see.

```
class SlideShow extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      slideIndex;
    };
    this.interval = null;

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.transitionToNextSlide.bind(this), 200);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    if(this.interval){
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  }

  transitionToNextSlide() {
    this.setState({this.state.slideIndex: (this.state.slideIndex + 1) % this.props.slides.length})


  render () {
    let containerStyle = {
      width:'100%'
    };

    return (
      <div style={containerStyle}>
          <Slide picture={this.props.pictures[this.state.currentSlide]}/>
      </div>
    );   
  }  
};
```